# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Desicion Tree

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I think Problem is with my variable 'info.venue'. Its actually String values, which i have encoded using labelencoder and hotoneencoder.
but its giving me error when i try to implement decision Tree. when I tried with only 2 variables, It worked like a charm. but when i used 'info.venue' using one Hot encoder its giving me following error.

Error is "Value Error: Setting an array element with a sequence"

```
info.toss.decision info.toss.winner  info.venue
        field            Australia  Shere Bangla National Stadium
        field            Australia  Adelaide Oval
        field            Australia  Melbourne Cricket Ground
        bat              Australia  Brabourne Stadium
        bat              Australia  Melbourne Cricket Ground
        bat              Australia  Sydney Cricket Ground
        bat              Australia  Punjab Cricket Association 
        field            India      Kensington Oval, Bridgetown
        field            India      Stadium Australia
       field             India      Saurashtra Cricket Association Stadium
        bat              India      Kingsmead
        bat              India      Melbourne Cricket Ground
        bat              India      R Premadasa Stadium
```

Code is as follows:

## Using LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder to encode data

```
> from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
> labelencoder=LabelEncoder() onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder()
> df['info.toss.decision'] =
> labelencoder.fit_transform(df['info.toss.decision'])
> df['info.toss.winner']=
> labelencoder.fit_transform(df['info.toss.winner'])
> df['info.outcome.winner']=
> labelencoder.fit_transform(df['info.outcome.winner'])
> df['info.venue']=labelencoder.fit_transform(df['info.venue'])
> df['info.venue']=onehotencoder.fit_transform(df[['info.venue']])
```

## select particular columns from the dataframe

```
X = df[['info.venue','info.toss.decision','info.toss.winner']]
Y = df[['info.outcome.winner']]
```

## Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.25)
```

## Fitting Decision Tree Classification to the Training set

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'gini', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The column 'info.venue' is as following;

```
info.venue

Kingsmead
Melbourne Cricket Ground
Brabourne Stadium
Kensington Oval, Bridgetown
Stadium Australia
Melbourne Cricket Ground
R Premadasa Stadium
Saurashtra Cricket Association Stadium
Shere Bangla National Stadium
Adelaide Oval
Melbourne Cricket Ground
Sydney Cricket Ground
Punjab Cricket Association IS Bindra Stadium, Mohali
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual input and output of your program

Comment: Please check the update.

Comment: Please focus on variable 'info.venue' coz I think thats where I am getting error.

Comment: @Dark Can u Code it and show me i.e where exactly I should make changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you are trying to assign a 2d array to a single column in pandas.

OneHotEncoder by default returns a sparse matrix, which is identified as an array of object by pandas. So what happens is pandas will accept that and broadcast that complete 2D object to all the rows of the dataframe. And then during the fitting of DecisionTree it will throw error.

So you need to change that:

```
ohe_data = onehotencoder.fit_transform(df[['info.venue']]).toarray()
for i in np.arange(onehotencoder.n_values_):
    df['infovenue_one_coded_'+str(i)]=ohe_data[:,i]
```

Then remove your original column from the dataframe:

```
new_df = df.drop('info.venue', 1)
```

And then pass this new_df to the DecisionTree.

**Update**:

Since you are converting to one hot encoded data first and then splitting it into train and test, I would recommend using `pd.get_dummies()`, which will replace both LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder from your code.

Replace these lines:

```
df['info.venue']=labelencoder.fit_transform(df['info.venue'])
df['info.venue']=onehotencoder.fit_transform(df[['info.venue']])
```

with

```
new_df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['info.venue'])], axis=1)
new_df = df.drop('info.venue', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can You code it and show it @Dark ? 
Coz I am not getting above code as it has some unknown variables like "enc.n_values_" can u use and get_dummies with concat and help me

Comment: what is enc.n_values_ ?? and 'infovenue_one_coded_ ?? @Vivek

Comment: @MayurMahajan I have corrected the code.` infovenue_one_coded` is just a new name given to columns containing the one_hot encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the X values are much like `[[0,0,1],0,2]` which ain't a correct 2D data and this will lead to `Setting an array element with a sequence`. As an alternative for  one_hot_encoder from scikit  you can use `get_dummies` from pandas and concat it to `dataframe` i.e

```
dummies =  df['info.venue'].str.get_dummies()
ndf = pd.concat([df.drop(['info.venue'],1),dummies],1)
```

Later you can split the ndf into X and Y. i.e

```
mask = ndf.columns.isin(['info.outcome.winner'])
# Were are using isin here because there will be huge number of columns generated due to get_dummies as sparse.    
X = ndf[ndf.columns[mask]].values
Y = ndf[ndf.columns[~mask]].values
```

Comment: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'Index'

Comment: What do You suggest which algorithm will be best if I want to use Venue ? Coz I basically I have n number of stadiums where matches are played by particular country ? you can check data above.

Comment: Since I cant use sparse matrix in DECISION tree, I am basically dropping the Idea of using venue as a field now. But it did work.